# How to check if **any** element exists in an `std::vector` at a given index

Tags: c++, c++14

I have an `std::vector` like this

`std::vector<std::pair<T,T>> xyz`.  `xyz` has a length of 10 and another function fills exactly 3 spots, say 4, 6, and 8 with `std::pair<T,T>`. While iterating through the vector, I want to know where the non-empty spots are there so that I can further work with the `std::pair<T,T>`s.

I think I can use `c++17`'s `std::optional<>` but I am using `c++14`. Is there any way to find out the spots in an `std::vector` which are not empty in c++14.

the vector will look something like this after assignment from the function

```
index  value
 0:
 1:
 2:
 3:
 4:    <7,8>
 5:
 6:    <9,2>
 7:
 8:    <8,6>
 9:
```

I want to iterate over the above vector and only say print the `std::pairs`

Comment: No spots are empty because all of them are initialised when you create the vector or resize it to 10 elements. If the other function sets them with some other value, you could check what the value is.

Comment: What defines an "empty" spot - do you mean a spot where there is no `std::pair`? Maybe just a simple `struct` with a `bool present` field would suffice? (this is the message @morpheus replied to, I probably shouldn't have removed it to reformulate...)

Comment: `std::map<int, YourData>` could be what you are looking for, if most of "spots" are empty and you only wish to iterate those which have been used already.

Comment: if you just store a few places in the vector then probably you should use `std::map`, `std::unordered_map`, or a sparse array. `std::optional` can be easily replaced with a pair or tuple that saves the initialization state

Comment: @L.Kärkkäinen the values are all different. I am not sure what to check it against. I have updated my questions lightly.

Comment: You can use `boost::optional` since C++11

Comment: You could use an std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::pair<T,T>>> and check for null pointers and skip over them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it if you don't do some work on your data-structure, for every element in vector is initialized.

The simplist and quickest way I think, is to store a `std::vector<bool>` of the same size to store whether a element is not only initialized, but "modified" later as well.

If you worry that you may forget to set the other vector, bind them together:

```cpp
std::vector<std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, bool>> a;
```

If you still think this is too ugly, you may have to implement your own simple `optional`

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be an acceptable way to do it.